# Using grep and map to find file names with the .png extension, but output them without the extension

Tags: perl, grep

Using **grep** and **map**, my Perl script returns file names (plant names) as "Genus_species.png". However, I would prefer outputting these file names without the .png extension. That said, I still want my **grep/map** expression to find only file names with the .png extension. How do I do this? Please advise. Thanks.

Here's my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir = '/Users/jdm/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/cnc/images/plants';
opendir my $dfh, $dir  or die "Can't open $dir: $!";

my @files = 
    map { s/1\.png\z/.png/r } # Removes "1" from "Genus_species1.png" file names/ also finds "Genus_species.png" file names
    grep { /^[^2-9]*\.png\z/i && /_/ } # Excludes file names with numbers 2-9 such as "Genus_species2-9.png"
    readdir $dfh; # Returns one file name per plant as "Genus_species.png" 

foreach my$file (@files) {
   print "$file\n";
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Ilex_verticillata.png
Asarum_canadense.png
Ageratina_altissima.png
Lonicera_maackii.png
Chelone_obliqua.png
Acalypha_deamii.png
```

Here's the preferred output without the .png extension:

```
Ilex_verticillata
Asarum_canadense
Ageratina_altissima
Lonicera_maackii
Chelone_obliqua
Acalypha_deamii
```

Again, I still want to find only file names with the .png extension, but output them without the .png extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put in the last loop:

```
$file =~s/\.png//;
```

Before print.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the extension with a substitution:

```
foreach my $file (@files) {
   print $file =~ s/\.png$//r, "\n";
}
```

or, you can use `substr`:

```
foreach my $file (@files) {
   print substr($file, 0, -4), "\n";
}
```

or, you can use a match:

```
foreach my $file (@files) {
   print $file =~ /(.*)\.png$/, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usage of [glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob) simplifies the problem

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $dir = '/Users/jdm/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/cnc/images/plants';
my @files = map { s/1|(2-9)|(\.png)//g; $_ } glob("$dir/*.png");

say for @files;
```

Comment: Interesting approach! I'll have to try using glob. Thank you.

Comment: That should be `glob("\Q$dir\E/*.png")`

Comment: You removed the filtering of undesired files the OP had.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to change `xxx1.png` ⇒ `xxx` and `xxx.png` ⇒ `xxx`.

To achieve that, simply replace

```perl
s/1\.png\z/.png/r
```

with

```perl
s/1?\.png\z//r
```